# Sleep when not used, wake up when used!

Tags: raspbian, power, vpn

I have a ongoing VPN project where I have installed OpenVPN on my Raspberry Pi. Everything works fine but the VPN is meant for just **myself** and so the Raspberry Pi is **unused** for a long time every day.

So to prevent this power-waste I need to make my Raspberry Pi sleep when it isn't being used and to wake up when a VPN connection is requested (LAN signal).

I have found some articles saying that the RPI use no power at all and I should just leave it on **BUT** because I'm a **enthusiastic RPI user** this have turned to be a **challenge** in which I need the community to help me to finish it.

Comment: To be completely honest with you there is no need to put the Pi into sleep mode. It uses hardly any electricity at all, your only going to see exceptionally marginal gains by making it sleep when you are not using it. The cost to leave it running on all the time year round is a few US dollars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say which Pi, but the later models reduce clock when not used. The only way you can save more is to remove power.

The circuitry to control power will cost more than the power in 10 years of use, so this would actually result in waste. This also adds the problem of detecting potential use.

You will find a few similar questions, but no solutions. The only real solutions are for those running on batteries/solar power.